# In BDD, what's the strategy to keep the not-yet-implemented tests separate from the implemented ones?

Tags: php, bdd, codeception, gherkin

In behaviour driven development, you write the tests first.

However, when you are in the middle of development and you have a functional but limited application, some tests will have been implemented and some will not have been.

How do you keep all the failures of the not-yet-implemented tests from obscuring the true errors?

Comment: Just don’t write any tests until you’re actually going to implement the behavior - then write one test at a time, following the typical cycle of development: red, green, refactor.

Comment: Sorry, that's not a solution or an option.  Writing features is part of the planning process.

Comment: Well, maybe you are doing your planning wrong, then.

Comment: Maybe also take a look at https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/116.

Comment: We're not allowed to write features in advance now?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3823

Mark the scenarios with a tag (e.g. incomplete) and then use:

```
codecept run functional --skip-group incomplete
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a tooling issue. But one solution that is available in many implementations is to tag scenarios. Those not done yet can be tagged wip, as in work in progress. Then you can just skip those in your build.

Writing features in advance is a good idea if you want them to drive the development. The trick is to write them late enough so they really drive the immediate development. Writing them weeks or months ahead is probably not the way to go. Writing them a day or a few hours before implementation is probably a better idea.